# Problem with porting VBScript from WinXP to Win7

Tags: windows-7, vbscript

The attached VBScript displays all available WiFi networks.
It works fine on WinXP, but doesn't work on Win7.
On WinXP it shows a list of all available WiFi networks, however on WIn7 it shows an empty list.
What is the problem?

```
on error resume next 
set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\wmi") 
set colInstances = objSwbemServices.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM MSNDis_80211_BSSIList") 
for each obj in colInstances 
    if left(obj.InstanceName, 4) <> "WAN " and right(obj.InstanceName, 8)     <> "Miniport" then 
        for each rawssid in obj.Ndis80211BSSIList 
            ssid = "" 
            for i=0 to ubound(rawssid.Ndis80211SSid) 
                decval = rawssid.Ndis80211Ssid(i) 
                if (decval > 31 AND decval < 127) then 
                    ssid = ssid & Chr(decval) 
                end if 
            next 
            wscript.echo ssid 
        next 
    end if 
next
```

I am a newbie with VBScript so please be gentle.

Comment: What happens when you run the script elevated?  I'm wondering if the WMI queries require admin privs, and simply fail when run as a standard user.   (In particular, the ExecQuery call seems like it might need admin privs, as it could do anything.)

Comment: Hi, Eric.

Thank you for your response.
I launched it from Administrator account with all admin privileges. The result is the same - empty message box.

Comment: What happens if you remove `on error resume next`? If the script fails, what error do you get and on which line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[I would comment, but not enough rep :P]
Visual Studio will allow you to debug a VBScript so you can determine which line in particular is causing the issue.

Navigate to the directory that contains the script, then run 'wscript .vbs //D //X' and then select Visual Studio as your debugger. You can then run through each line and get an idea of what is happening ([source](http://theopensourceu.com/2009/05/debug-vbscript-with-visual-studio/)).

When I execute this script (both with normal and elevated privileges) I receive an empty array from the query "SELECT * FROM MSNDis_80211_BSSIList". This may be where the issue is stemming from; maybe having the source (MSNDis_80211_BSSIList) deprecated and renamed in Windows 7.

A Google also revealed a possible correlation between the latest set of drivers (such as the Intel Wifi drivers) which may contain the WMI additions.